# Passing an object property into a closure in PHP

Tags: php, closures

I am trying to pass an object property into a closure (that's within a method of that object), like so:

```
class Entity extends ControllerBase {
  private $view;
  private $events;
  public function print($tid) {
    self::loadView($tid);
    self::loopView();
    return (new StreamedResponse(function() use ($this->events){
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

The $events property gets instantiated in the `loopView()` method. This seems like it should work to me, but I get this error:

```
ParseError: syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR), expecting ',' or ')' in ...
```

It seems to be saying it doesn't expect there to be an object referenced in `use`. I don't know why this isn't valid, and after some googling, I couldn't find anything referencing my specific problem.

In PHP 7.1.7, is it possible to do this, and if so, what is the correct syntax?

Comment: pass `$this->events` into a new variable, because `$this` have a another meaning inside the anymous funciton

Comment: Worst case, you can set `$evt = $this->events` then pass it to `use()`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can just use `$this->events` in the closure without a `use` statement.

See "Automatic Binding of `$this`" in [the anonymous function documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php).

> As of PHP 5.4.0, when declared in the context of a class, the current class is automatically bound to it, making $this available inside of the function's scope.

For example: https://3v4l.org/gYdHp

---

As far as the reason for the parse error, if we disregard the specific `$this` case,

```
function() use ($object->property) { ...
```

doesn't work because `use` passes *variables* from the parent scope into the closure, and
`$object->property` is not a variable, it is an expression.

If you need to refer to an object property inside a closure, you either need to `use` the entire object, or assign the property to another variable you can `use`. But in this case you don't have to worry about that since `$this` is special.